# Upload to S3 return Forbidden

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, sails.js

I have a form to upload file to my bucket in aws S3 and this is the form

```
<form action="/user/fileUpload" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="ui form" method="post">

  <div class="field">
    <select class="ui dropdown">
      <option value="">Print Agency</option>
      <option value="fastprint">Fast Print</option>
      <option value="printpress">Print Press</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <input type="file" name="uploadFile" />
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="ui blue submit button" />
  </div>

</form>
```

and this is the action that will active if I press the submit button

```
fileUpload: function(req, res) {
req.file('uploadFile').upload({
  adapter: require('skipper-s3'),
  key: 'THE-KEY',
  secret: 'THE-SECRET',
  bucket: 'THE-BUCKET'
}, function (err, filesUploaded) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return res.negotiate(err);
  }
  return res.ok({
    files: filesUploaded,
    textParams: req.params.all()
  });
});}
```

This is my S3 CORS Configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

And This is my S3 Bucket Policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1433335661532",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1433335656754",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET-NAME/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET-NAME"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

but always result forbidden. I don't know why.
result image:

[image: http://imgur.com/MMtingu.]

And I really need your help here.

**UPDATE WITH ANSWER**

After thinking about @tom answer I found out how stupid I am after I know all of this because I forgot to put few line.

I should put this line inside routes.js

```
'post /user/fileUpload': {
controller: 'UserController',
action: 'fileUpload'},
```

And this line below the submit button because I use CSRF

```
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<%= _csrf %>" />
```

And this line inside UserController action fileUpload, bellow 'bucket'

```
ACL: 'public-read'
```

Regards,

Elmer

Comment: do you see anything from you console.log(err) ?

Comment: @Meeker: nothing from console.log(err).. It seems the problem is the S3 permission. And I already Grantee Permission to Everyone to list and update/delete. And I also already add the COSR and Bucket Policy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If console.log(err) is indeed null as you mentioned in the comments, it's quite unlikely that it's a problem with s3, as there's no reason for sails to return a 403 if this passes.

Instead I'd suggest to check if `fileUpload` is ever called. If it is not, make sure the policies are setup correctly and that you may access that controller's method.

Comment: the `fileUpload` is indeed called. Afterall when user submit the form, the url change to http://localhost:1337/user/uploadFile. Isn't it means that the action `fileUpload` is called? And the policies.js is already `'*': true`

Comment: The only way this may return an error then would be via the err object, it literally cannot be null.

Comment: Well, when I submit the form, I didn't see any change. the only thing that show on my terminal is the thing after I did `sails lift`.

Anyway, thx for your response, at least I don't have to think about any error right?

Comment: Hi @tom, after I search the problem thoroughly, I found out that the fileUpload is never ever called as you said. Silly but big mistake I did there.